# Linq query to obtain count from a List

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I am trying to construct a LINQ query in c# for the following scenario.

> "Given a particular token "to identify the count of documents in which
>   it exists"

```
private List<Document> documents = new List<Document>();

class Document
{
    string filename;
    public string FileName { get { return filename; } }
    Dictionary<string, int> tokens;
    public Dictionary<string, int> Tokens { get { return tokens; } }

    public Document(string filename, Dictionary<string, int> tokens)
    {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.tokens = tokens;
    }
}
```

With my knowledge I came up with this expression:

```
documents.Where(d => d.Tokens.Keys.Any(k => k == word)).Count();
```

But I am not sure whether it is 100% correct. In need of some expert advice on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make use of the O(1) lookup time of the dictionary you should use `ContainsKey` instead.

```
documents.Count(d => d.Tokens.ContainsKey(word));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can actually perform the filtering in the `Count` method:

```
documents.Count(d => d.Tokens.Keys.Any(k => k == word));
```

Beyond that, I think your query is correct.